# Django admin delete != Model.delete()

Tags: python, django

In our codebase, `T` which is a `Model`, has a foreign key dependency on a Model `P` (with `on_delete=CASCADE`), has a many-to-many field on Model `C`, and so on.

My support task is to delete all `T`s whose `p__name` (p is the foreign key reference to `P`) belongs to a set of 500+ values.

I experimented with two approaches:
1. To log into the django admin portal and delete an individual instance of `T` from there.
2. I also tried to do the following `t = T.objects.get(p__name="..some-name.."); t.delete()`

Approach #1 seems to clean up all linkages. Where as approach #2 could not delete the model pointed to by  `t.p`. Both the approaches hit the `Model.delete()` method and I have verified this. Yet, #1 is more effective than #2. However, #1 is manual and #2 is programmatic (and, therefore, desirable).

I am looking for a programmatic method which could replicate the delete action from admin site.

**Solution** - The programmatic way to delete `T`s turned out to be delete `P`s. I have accepted Alasdair's answer. I still have not found the reason behind the non-equivalence of #1 and #2. That is for some another day.

Comment: You can control this behaviour via on_delete: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood how cascade works. If I understand your question correctly, your models are something like:

```
class P(models.Model):
    pass

class T(models.Model):
    # on_delete=models.CASCADE is the default, including it here to be explicit
    p = models.ForeignKey(P, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Deleting a `t` will not cause the related `p` to be deleted. The CASCADE means that if you delete a `p`, then all `t`'s that link to `p` will be deleted.

```
p = P.objects.get(name="x")
p.delete() # all t's that link to p will be deleted.
```

This is the case whether you use the Django admin or do it programmatically.

Comment: Thanks Alasdair. You have understood my models correctly. I will try deleting the `P`s first and see if deletes `T`s automatically. However, the above mentioned difference in the behaviors still stand.

Comment: Deleting `T`s should not remove `P`s, whether in the admin or not. If that is really happening for you, there must be something in your models that you haven't shown us.